# How to start a activity with in another activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest

This is  my piece of code.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    for (int n = 0; n > messages.length; n++) {
    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }
    // show first message
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
    "Received SMS Call Now ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    String call = "*wefewfefe";    
    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); // ACTION_CALL                               
    Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", call, "#"); 
    intent.setData(uri2);                                
    context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

as the intent start the application forcefully closed.

Comment: Did you added the permission?

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>